# How to consume events delivered by Azure Event Grid to GCP

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, azure-eventgrid

Basically what I understood from few `Azure` topics is as below:

1. `Azure Event Hub` - where data is received initially and converted into events
2. `Service Bus`- acting as a queue
3. `Azure Event Grid` - where events converted in hub are transferred here.

so the connection is like below:

```
Hub -> Service Bus -> Event Grid -> Pub Sub -> Storage
```

I understood this concept. My problem is I want data to be pushed from the event grid to GCP (subscription / topics). My question are:

- How can I establish this using `PUSH` method?
- What do I need to develop exactly?
- How can I push things from `grid` to `pubsub/subscriptions`?

I found [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/event-grid-java-publish-consume-events/) where data is getting published into Event Grid `but I want to push data from the event grid to gcp`. Can anybody explain me where am I going wrong or what exactly should I start with. I am new to this and its very confusing so I just need little bit of guidance over here.

I have below doubts:

1. Is there any direct subscriber option available with event grid listener? I mean can I directly link my google storage account with this listener so, whenever there is an event triggered it will be directly pushed to my GCP account(I don't have Azure account with me right now since access issue is in progress so I can't see it that's why I am asking here)
2. Suppose I have `20 columns` in my data but I want only `16 columns` to be pushed in GCP so is there any customization possible while sending data from `event grid/event hub` to `pub/sub`
3. If I write custom connectors code as per the links provided in the below answers then how can I run it? I mean where I can deploy those scripts on the cloud so that they will be triggered automatically whenever an event is triggered?
4. Can I implement webhooks in this scenario? (as an alternative to connectors), If yes then how can I do it and on which side do I need to create it?
5. Also, I read some articles and I came to know from a few guys that they experienced data loss in this entire process. So, what's the possibility over here and how can it be avoided

Comment: why you are mixing up both GCP and Azure?

Comment: this is my requirement

Comment: That is a weird requirement though! which would end up in high cost. why cant you use task queue in gcp?

Comment: anything is fine for me as of now. At this point of time I just want to transfer data from azure to gcp . It can be pubsub/ task queue.

Comment: any help here ?

Comment: The scope of this question keeps growing more and more. You would be better off asking separate, concise questions.

Comment: It's related to the same topic that's why I avoided posting a separate question

Comment: But you now have five relatively independent "doubts" that could probably be proposed as separate questions. This is becoming a large-scale design question with lots of smaller parts. For example, where to run the code to go from Event Grid to Cloud Pub/Sub is a question independent of how to filter our columns in the code itself. You also say "few guys that they experienced data loss in this entire process" without talking about what part of the process or linking to the articles. With so many questions and lack of details, it is going to be difficult to give a concise, reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody explain me where am I going wrong or what exactly should I start with.

It's right here:

> so the connection is like below:
> `Hub -> Service Bus -> Event Grid -> Pub Sub -> Storage`

Although this *might* be the case, it sounds very much as if you're looking at one (very) specific scenario where data flows in this exact way.

Azure Event Hub, Azure Service Bus and Azure Event Grid *can* work together, but can also be used completely separate from each other.

**Event Grid**
The purpose of Event Grid is to enable *Reactive programming*. Use this when you want to react to (status) changes.

**Event Hubs**
Event Hubs facilitate a *big data pipeline*. Use this when you need telemetry and distributed data streaming.

**Service Bus**
The purpose of Service bus is to enable *High-value enterprise messaging*. Use this when you want to do something like Order processing and financial transactions.

> In some cases, you use the services side by side to fulfill distinct roles. For example, an ecommerce site can use Service Bus to process the order, Event Hubs to capture site telemetry, and Event Grid to respond to events like an item was shipped.
>
> In other cases, you link them together to form an event and data pipeline. You use Event Grid to respond to events in the other services. For an example of using Event Grid with Event Hubs to migrate data to a data warehouse, see Stream big data into a data warehouse.

Taken from the very interesting and important documentation article [Choose between Azure messaging services - Event Grid, Event Hubs, and Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services)

**EDIT**

> My problem is I want data to be pushed from event grid to GCP (subscription / topics). So how can I establish this using `PUSH` method??

Possibly the simplest solution is to have an Event Grid Event trigger a webhook (which might run an [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) or a [Google Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/)) which in turn puts the event/message on the GCP Topic.

[Publishing messages](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher) is quite well documented. There are examples on how to do so with a REST call, command-line, C#, Go, JAVA, NodeJS, PHP, Python and Ruby.

**EDIT 2**
What you need to do is create an [Event Grid Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/concepts#event-subscriptions) to listen to and handle Event Grid Events.
Here's an example screenshot on how to listen for events for a specific Storage Account and call a WebHook whenever such an event occurs:
[image: Event Grid Subscription]

Pay attention to the "Endpoint Details": that's where you can specify to, for instance, call a webhook every time an event is triggered.

Comment: This answer explains the difference, but i feel actual question is different.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will start going through these codes and will let you know if my requirement is not satisfied

Comment: I have seen those links but I am confused. How can I establish connection between event grid and pubsub. What exactly I need to build. A publisher /subscriber ? Can you help me with little bit coding snippets just to get started. Once I am clear with the connection then I can try to do the rest @rickvdbosch

Comment: My question is how can I listen to calls made by event grid . I cannot see any HTTP requests

Comment: I have few more doubts. As per second image, I need to create event grid subscription on Azure. am i correct ? so what is webhook . Is it different from google cloud function.If i want to get messages on GCP side then what exactly I need to configure over here.According to me, I will have to provide webhook and create google cloud function.Can you correct me over here. It would be helpful if you put some steps like create google cloud function first then provide some value from GCF to webhook over here. Im not sure but something like this. I may be wrong but this whole environment is new to me

Comment: Also, do I need to create any custom java code after creating this subscription ??

Comment: I figured out that I need to create google cloud function and pass on that URL in event  grid listener subscription but I am not sure how to write code for listening to these events in google cloud functions using node js / python. Any guidance here please

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions as comments on an answer, but open a new question. If this answers your intial question: mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can you help me with my 5 doubts ??@rickvdbosch

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to transfer the EventHub generated events would probably be to create an EventHub event receiver in Node.js (which you mentioned in your comments) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send#review-the-sample-code-1), which receives events and publishes them to Cloud Pub/Sub directly, as described [in the Cloud Pub/Sub publisher documentation for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#pubsub-publish-message-nodejs).

Comment: I have flow like this eventhub > eventgridlistener > pub/sub. Can I exclude eventgrid listener?

Comment: Also, the link you provided reads events from event hub but how can I push it to pub/sub. Can you help me to establish code link between these two since I am new to these concepts so that it will help to understand better and I can complete the rest. It would be very kind of yours. Thanks @Daniel

Comment: There is no explicit integration between eventhub and Pub/Sub.  However, EventHub provides you the ability to receive events in Node, from which you could then use the Cloud Pub/Sub Publisher client library directly.

Comment: I didn't get you. What do you mean by "nodes"  here. Can you provide some flow so that I can understand

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to Node.js, the javascript environment, not a 'node' concept.  You could equivalently use Java or C#.

Comment: okay but  how to develop a code flow in this case. Can you  help me with that

Comment: To my knowledge, 'code flow' is not a well defined concept.  If you want to write messages that originate in EventHub to Cloud Pub/Sub, you can do so using the EventHub apis I linked to, in any language that Pub/Sub also supports, which would be Java, Python, C#, Node.js, and Go.  Where you run this code is up to you.

Comment: I have edited my question with more doubts. Could you please look into it ?

Comment: Can you answer my doubts ?