# How can I use Google Cloud Pub/Sub in Azure functions?

Tags: azure

Need to pick the messages from Azure Service Bus and publish those message into Google cloud pub/sub. I want to use Azure functions not Azure web job.
Thanks

Comment: Of course you can. What is stopping you? What have you tried so far (that is not working)?

Comment: You might want to take a look over here: [How to consume events delivered by Azure Event Grid to GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533597/how-to-consume-events-delivered-by-azure-event-grid-to-gcp)